# Error loading xml in php (not absolute)

Tags: php, xml, namespaces

I am trying tom load an XML document with multiple namespace declarations
My php is:

```
<?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8'); 
$doc->load( 'UBLCatalog.xml' ); 

$Items = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS( "UBLCommonAggregateComponents","Item" ); 
foreach( $Items as $Item ) 
{ 
 $descriptions = $Item->getElementsByTagNameNS( "UBLCommonBasicComponents","Description" ); 
 $description = $descriptions->item(0)->nodeValue;  

 echo "<b>$description\n</b><br>"; 
 } 
?>
```

The error is:

> xmlns: URI UBLCatalogDocument is not absolute in
>   file:///C:/wamp/www/XMLExperiments/UBLCatalog.xml,

I am getting output, but the error is annoying.

The verbatim error is: Notice: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlns: URI UBLCatalogDocument is not absolute in file:///C:/wamp/www/XMLExperiments/UBLCatalog.xml, line: 4 in C:\wamp\www\XMLExperiments\ItemsXml.php on line 3

And, if I remove the default namespace (xmlns="UBLCatalogDocument") the error goes away

Comment: Can you share the XML format here for others to see. Would help in understanding the structure.

Comment: What line is causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

PHP XML extenstions (DOM, XMLReader, SimpleXml etc.) [use libxml library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.libxml.php) to parse XML files.

The reason of this error is that **libxml expects absolute URL in `xmlns` atttibute** (i.e. `xmlns="http://example.com/some-unique-url"`), but gets only text (`xmlns="UBLCatalogDocument"`).

From the [libxml webpage](http://www.xmlsoft.org/namespaces.html):

> The namespace value has to be an absolute URL, but the URL doesn't
>   have to point to any existing resource on the Web.

**So if it's possible, change your `xmlns` attribute to some absolute URL.**

Answer (score 1):

Finding your nodes using XPath might get rid of your error:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$Items = $xpath->query('//item[@xmlns="UBLCommonAggregateComponents"]');
```