# Warnings when loading XML using simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file named po.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DOCUMENT xmlns="po.xsd">
        <PO>
            <HEADER>
                <PO_CODE/>
                <PO_NAME/>
                <REFF_NO/>
            </HEADER>
            <DETAIL>
                <CONT>
                    <NO_CONT/>
                    <UK_CONT/>
                    <NO_SEGEL/>
                    <JNS_CONT/>
                    <ISO_CODE/>
                </CONT>
            <DETAIL>
        </PO>
    </DOCUMENT>
```

When I load the file using the following PHP script:

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file('po.xml');
```

I get these warnings:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): po.xml:2: namespace warning : xmlns: URI po.xsd >is not absolute in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\po.php on line 3
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file():  in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\po.php on line 3
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\po.php on line >3');

I want to echo the XML structure of po.xml as a string.

Answer (score 0):

this sample xml is invalid. try closing the `<DETAIL>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your xml

First, the `xmlns="po.xsd"` should use absolute path.

From the libxml webpage http://www.xmlsoft.org/namespaces.html:

> The namespace value has to be an absolute URL, but the URL doesn't have to point to any existing resource on the Web.

This question have been discussed here: [Error loading xml in php (not absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10986913/2377164)

if you remove or fix this part with something like `xmlns="http://www.example.com/po.xsd"` it should works.

And as mentioned by Jeff Pucket, your tag `<DETAIL>` should be closed

```
<DETAIL>
   <CONT>
   <NO_CONT/>
   ....
   </CONT>
</DETAIL>
```